# Javascript callback within event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, event-handling, jquery-callback

I am currently trying to implement a system where a callback is triggered from within an event listener (code below). When I run the code, I get the error "callback is not a function", which I believe to be because the variable callback is not defined by the event listener.

```
function playSound(no, callback) {
var noOfSounds = sound().length;
if(no == "random" || no == undefined) {
    act("There are "+noOfSounds+" Sounds");
    var randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * noOfSounds);
    act("Will use no."+randomNo);
    playSound(randomNo);
} else {
    sound()[no].addEventListener("ended", function() {

        callback();

    });
    sound()[no].play();
}}
```

Comment: you haven't passed callback function when called `playSound(randomNo);`

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, I am calling the playSound function from another function when this error is occurring, I am not bothered with the call from inside the function just yet (I will add some logic in later to determine if a callback has been passed). TL;DR: This error still occurs if a callback is passed.

Comment: you Need to Show us more code. For example where you are calling the playsound function and the callback function you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the way you are calling the function. If I look at line 10 you are saying

```
 playSound(randomNo)
```

It should be

```
 playSound(randomNo, function(){
    //code to execute in callback
});
```

This is because you are calling trying to use callback which is a function and should be added to the input parameters when calling the method.